# COUNT within a WHERE clause or HAVING?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is basically what I am trying to achieve;

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT No) 
FROM 
Table 
WHERE 
(Type = 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT No) > Num) 
OR (Type = 2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT No) > Num) 
GROUP BY
Week
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any aggregate comparisons need to go into a HAVING clause after the Group By.  Just remember that you may get different results depending on where you put your non-aggregate conditional, because you'll be aggregating over what you've included/excluded via the WHERE.

ie

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT No) 
FROM Table 
WHERE Type = 1
GROUP BY Week
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT No) > Num
```

may be different from

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT No) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Week
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT No) > Num
AND Type = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get an error message saying that Type is invalid in the Having clause because not contained in aggregate... Do I need to add it to the group by?

Comment: Ooops, that's a good point.  The latter statement won't work as Type isn't being grouped by or it isn't an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT No) 
FROM 
Table 
WHERE Type = 1 OR Type = 2
GROUP BY
Week
Having COUNT(DISTINCT No) > Num
```

This is Possible Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT No) as num1
FROM TableName
WHERE Type IN (1,2)  
GROUP BY Week
HAVING num1 > Num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT Week, Type, COUNT(DISTINCT No) WeekTally
    FROM   [Table]
   WHERE  Type in (1,2)
GROUP BY Week, Type
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT No) > @Num
ORDER BY Week, Type;
```

If you're grouping by Week, surely you want to see which week the count is for?!